# Get html table info from View to Controller

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, view, controller

I'm working with ASP.NET MVC, and I have a dynamic table in my view, the user can add and delete rows.

```
<table class="table" id="tableClasses">
        <tr>
            <th>Class</th>
            <!-- Icon to add a line. Done with javascript -->
            <th><span class="table-add glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></th>
        </tr>
        @foreach (string sClass in tClasses)
        {
            <tr>
                <td contenteditable="true">@sClass</td>
                <td>
                    <span class="table-remove glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
        <!-- This is our clonable table line -->
        <tr class="hide">
            <td contenteditable="true">New Class</td>
            <td>
                <!-- Icon to remove the line. Done with javascript -->
                <span class="table-remove glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

I need to retrieve and save the values from all the lines in my controller, but I don't know how to do it.

Since I don't know how many lines there will be in the table, I can't use id right?

How can I access and loop through the table cells in the controller ?

EDIT :

Here is the controller code :

```
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "PKAL,FKHC,SIATA,SICAO,SNAME,SETDEARLY,SETDLATE,SLASTMIN,SCLASSFASTLANE,SDCSINTERFACE")] AIRLINE aIRLINE)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                aIRLINE.SETDEARLY = aIRLINE.SETDEARLY.Replace(":", string.Empty);
                aIRLINE.SETDLATE = aIRLINE.SETDLATE.Replace(":", string.Empty);
                aIRLINE.SLASTMIN = aIRLINE.SLASTMIN.Replace(":", string.Empty);
```

`FormCollection collection = new FormCollection();  
            collection.Get("classTemp");

            db.Entry(aIRLINE).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        ViewBag.FKHC = new SelectList(db.HANDLER, "PKHC", "SHCODE", aIRLINE.FKHC);
        return View(aIRLINE);
    }`

The tricky thing is that the SCLASSFASTLANE is stored as "A,B,C,X" in the database.

That's why I am using a custom template to display and modify it, and that I need a dynamic table (code above).

Comment: Do you mind posting your controller code? Also, you're gonna have to enclose that in `<form>` or use jquery to do a `POST`.

Comment: You don't appear to have a form, and even if you did, you not generating any form controls so there is nothing to post to the controller. You will need to use javascript/jquery to get the values and ajax to post them to your controller. You could give the `<td>` elements a class name, or just use loop each `<tr>` element and get its first `<td>` element.

Comment: I posted the controller code.
I tried using a form surrounding the <table> element but it doesn't seem to work.

Do you have an example of how I could do that with jquery and Ajax?

Comment: Why on earth are you using `<td contenteditable`? Impossible to understand what your trying to do based on this code, but I suggest you go to the MVC site and work through some tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally managed to solve it, here is what I ended up doing :

Here is the View (EditorTemplate) Code (didn't change much):

```
<div id="table" class="table-editable">
<table id="tableClasses" class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>@Resource.ClassFastLane</th>
        <th><span class="table-add glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (string sClass in tClasses)
    {
        <tr>
            <td contenteditable="true">@sClass</td>
            <td>
                <span class="table-remove glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
    <!-- This is our clonable table line -->
    <tr class="hide">
        <td contenteditable="true"></td>
        <td>
            <span class="table-remove glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I retrieved the values from the table via javascript :

```
<script>
    //Store the class html table values in a string array and post it to the controller.
    //function returnClasses() {
    $("form").submit(function (e) {
        //On empêche le formulaire de faire un submit.
        e.preventDefault();

        //On sauve les données de la table des classes vers le controller.
        var TableData = new Array();
        $('#tableClasses tr').each(function (row, tr) {
            TableData = TableData + $(tr).find('td:eq(0)').text();
        });
        var postData = { values: TableData };

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/AIRLINE/SaveClasses",
            //url: "/ControllerHelper/SaveClasses",
            data: postData,
            success: function (result) {
                submit();
            },
        });
    })
    //Une fois les données sauvées, on fait le submit.
    function submit() {
        $("form").unbind('submit').submit();
    }
</script>
```

I prevent the form to submit, submit the class values, then in the controller, I rearrange the values the way I want them to be, and submit the form via the Edit ActionResult :

```
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "PKAL,FKHC,SIATA,SICAO,SNAME,SETDEARLY,SETDLATE,SLASTMIN,SCLASSFASTLANE,SDCSINTERFACE")] AIRLINE aIRLINE)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            aIRLINE.SCLASSFASTLANE = ControllerHelper.getClassesTemp();
            ControllerHelper.resetClassesTemp();

            db.Entry(aIRLINE).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        ViewBag.FKHC = new SelectList(db.HANDLER, "PKHC", "SHCODE", aIRLINE.FKHC);
        return View(aIRLINE);
    }
```

It's probably not the prettiest solution, but with the knowledge I have so far and the little help I could get, it will do just fine for now.